# jquery problem with anchor click() method

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

Among other things I have this html content in my content page:

```
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[ID$=panelDetail]").dialog({
        autoOpen: false
        , resizable: false
        , height: 'auto'
        , width: 'auto'
        , modal: true
        , overlay: { opacity: 0.8, background: "black" }
    });

    function loadDialog(action) {
        $("[ID$=panelDetail]").dialog('open');
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "HTML",
            url: action,
            data: {},
            success: function(response) {
                $("#panelDetail").html('');
                $("#panelDetail").html(response);
            }
        });
    }

    $("[ID$=btnAdd]").click(function() {
        alert("click on add");
        loadDialog("/Foro/Create", "");
    });
</script>
</asp:Content>
```

I have then this HTML fragments in two separated  sections

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="BodyContent" runat="server">
    <div id="panelDetail" style="display:none" title="Panel Title"></div>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content4" ContentPlaceHolderID="RightPanel" runat="server">
    <a href="#" id="btnAdd">Add new</a>
    <a href="#" id="btnEdit">Edit</a>
</asp:Content>
```

Why the alert inside the  tag does never get called???

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap your calls in a `document.ready` call, like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a[ID$=btnAdd]").click(function() {
    alert("click on add");
    loadDialog("/Foro/Create", "");
  });
});
```

Otherwise the elements aren't there to be found yet :)  `document.ready` handlers fire when the DOm's fully loaded, e.g. your links are there to be found.

In the case of UpatePanels, switch to [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/), like this:

```
$(function() {
  $("a[ID$=btnAdd]").live('click', function() {
    alert("click on add");
    loadDialog("/Foro/Create", "");
  });
});
```

Comment: You're right. I feel stupid, now. Thank you! Just a curiosity: does "$(function() {})" is a shorthand for "$(document).ready(function() {})"?

Comment: @Lorenzo - live and learn, as long as you're not living it *after* learning it you're doing just fine :)

Comment: @Lorenzo - Yep that's correct, they're interchangeable, I just type it many times in a day, so I prefer the short version personally.